# Auto Generated Schema only works when done in Memory

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I generated a Json Schema off of a currently existing class.

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();                    
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Client));
```

This will validate fine, however, I need to put on dependencies (which you can't do from the class), so I copied the Schema results to a file.  Now, the file will validate as fine on http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/.  However, when I try to load it using the following:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("c:\\myJson.json"))
{
    file.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
    {
        JSchema schema2 = JSchema.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

I will always get errors on any internal references in the file:

```
"Contact": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Contact"},

An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaReaderException'
occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not resolve schema reference 
'#/definitions/Contact/ Path 'definitions.Contact' Line 120, position 20
```

Why would this be fine if done in memory, but if loaded from a file will fail?

Comment: Do the schema "Contact" exist in the definitions section of the schema?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem.  While you can generate your schema from your existing models, it may not always do it correctly.

We found that some of the classes referenced were added with an extra Item layer in them (not sure why)  Once we removed the reference of "Item" at the end, it worked fine.  It also generated a second Item layer in the object, which I had to remove to get validation to work on that object.